# How do I check which module causes LINK1112 error?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, linker

Is there a way to tell the full path of every DLL used while compiling?

I am trying to make a DLL with easy-to-Marshal functions to communicate between a C# application and a filesystem Minifilter (currently using the Minispy sample to check if everything is running smoothly).

It was successfully compiling and running when using "Win32" as my target platform in Visual Studio 2013, but when printing out pointers with printf("%p",...); their length was only 8 characters where they should have been 16 (my computer is 64 bits) which threw off future pointer juggling.

My active solution platform has always been x64 for the other projects. Unfortunately, changing the platform in the Configuration Manager to x64 for the DLL generates the following error during compilation:

> Error 1   error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

I checked online and this seems to be a configuration problem of some part of the solution, but all my projects should be compiling in x64. Cleaning and rebuilding to remove old files had no effect either.

I have used dumpbin.exe to check the Machine types of the DLLs I think my library is linking to and everything seems in order. I got these by checking the linker command line options in my project's Properties, but their names don't show where they are read from ( ex: kernel32.lib; user32.lib; gdi32.lib; fltLib.lib ... ). Since I'm still having this problem, I think it might be linking to the wrong (32bit) versions of the same DLLs.

Is there a way to tell the full path of every DLL used while compiling? Or better yet, is there a way to tell which DLL specifically is causing the LINK1112 error?

I have used the /VERBOSE:LIB command and removed the /NOLOGO option but the output is underwhelming, stopping right after the command to be executed with no other information.

Comment: Use /VERBOSE and search the output for LNK1112. It should get you right to the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have answered this when I solved it a couple months ago but I forgot I posted it here. But I'll try to recall what I did.

In the end, if I remember correctly, I'm pretty sure that what saved me was using Dependency Walker on the successfully compiled (x86) library. I used it before, but I was running it in the wrong mode (x64 or x86) and using the correct one revealed the missing modules for the x64 architecture.